# Get message count in ActiveMQ queue or receiver in c#

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm at consumer end and reading message from a queue. How to get the count of the total messages in a queue (IDestination) and pass number of messages (let's say 100 messages) at a time to the receiver.
Please help to achieve it in c# .Net

Answer (score 0):

One means of achieving this would be to enable the [Statistics Broker Plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin) and then send control commands to the broker from your C# client to obtain statistics on Queues you are interested in.  The follow is a Java based example but you could produce something quite similar using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ if that is what you are using for your C# client.

```
Queue replyTo = session.createTemporaryQueue();
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyTo);

Queue testQueue = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(null);

String queueName = "ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination." + testQueue.getQueueName()
Queue query = session.createQueue(queueName);

Message msg = session.createMessage();

producer.send(testQueue, msg) 
msg.setJMSReplyTo(replyTo);
producer.send(query, msg);
MapMessage reply = (MapMessage) consumer.receive();
assertNotNull(reply);
assertTrue(reply.getMapNames().hasMoreElements());
    
for (Enumeration e = reply.getMapNames();e.hasMoreElements();) {
    String name = e.nextElement().toString();
    System.err.println(name + "=" + reply.getObject(name));
}
```

That would allow you to see data such as:

```
memoryUsage=0  
dequeueCount=0  
inflightCount=0  
messagesCached=0  
averageEnqueueTime=0.0  
destinationName=queue://TEST.FOO  
size=1  
memoryPercentUsage=0  
producerCount=0  
consumerCount=0  
minEnqueueTime=0.0  
maxEnqueueTime=0.0  
dispatchCount=0  
expiredCount=0  
enqueueCount=1  
memoryLimit=67108864
```

Comment: I will try this out, thank you. One more doubt is, consumer.receive will only received single message, and consumer.listener will invoke at the last, if I want to take count while reading individual message in consumer.listener method, it is always calling at last and not able to call any other method to get the result from this listener.

Comment: I can't really parse what you are asking, I'd recommend maybe asking a new question on SO if you have other concerns or issues.